# A bad_alloc bug in C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++, can someone explain why the below codes throw a bad_alloc bug? Is this because before the initialization of `v_`, the `v_` has an undefined large size?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Test {
public:
  std::vector<int> v_;

  Test(): v_(v_) {}
};

int main() {
  Test t;
}
```

Comment: In the initializer list, you're attempting to initialize `v_` with itself. Anyway, it seems like you want to default-initialize `v_`, so just type `Test() = default;` or remove the ctor altogether. Btw. it's always a good idea to enable more warnings, so the compiler can help you in locating such mistakes. Not sure about yours, but e.g. for gcc/clang try to always compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: @andreee I would rather removed constructor at all

Comment: Oh true - overlooked that...

Comment: When behaviour is undefined, no real point in trying to explain what happens.   Better to take steps to ensure there is no undefined behaviour.   Initialising a class member with itself gives undefined behaviour.